# JPA repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have added a new OneToMany relation ant it appears that error:

```
ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: org.udg.pds.simpleapp_javaee.model.Comment column: id (should be mapped with insert=\"false\" update=\"false\")"}}
```

I want to have two relationships OneToMany from Movie to UserMovieValoration and Comment.
That's my code:

```
@Entity
public class Movie implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@JsonView(Views.Private.class)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@JsonView(Views.Private.class)
private String name;
private Long year;
private String sinopsis;
private Long duration;
private String idioma;
private String trailer;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "movie")
@JsonIgnore
Set<UserMovieValoration> userMovieValorations =  new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="movie")
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

The comments relation produces the error. How I can fix it.

thats my Comment code, where I have the ManyToOne relation with Movie.

```
@Entity
public class Comment implements Serializable {
/**
 * Default value included to remove warning. Remove or modify at will. *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public Comment() {
}


public Comment(String comentari){
    this.comentari = comentari;
    this.date = new Date();
}

@Id
@JsonView(Views.Private.class)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected Long id;

@JsonView(Views.Private.class)
private String comentari;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date date;



@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private Movie movie;
```

}

Comment: how does the comment entity look like?

Comment: The error message clearly says that the problem is in the Comment entity. But you didn't post any line of it.

Comment: I think you have added two columns named `id` in your Comment entity. One is the simple `Private Long id` and another is `@JoinColumn(name=id)` which actually should be `@JoinColumn(name=movie_id)`

Comment: Sorry, I have jjust added the Coment code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rename the column like this

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="movie_id")
private Movie movie